# How to rename files and directory with *.~1~ suffix to original name?

Tags: files, rename

I have a directory named `underscore.~1~` and several files inside with names like  `main.js.~1~`, `index.js.~1~` etc.

How can I rename the directory `underscore` and the files inside to the original names `main.js`, `index.js` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it (in bash) would be to change into the directory and do something like:

```
for i in *.~1~; do mv $i ${i%.~1~}; done
```

The above will iterate over all the `*.~1` files and move them to their equivalent without the extension (specified by the `${i%.~1~}` target). Look up your shell's textual substitutions.

You can do something similar for directories, but if you only have one directory there, it's simpler to just do it manually

```
mv underscore.~1~ underscore
```

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal can you not simply move the folder & files using `mv` command?

#### Example

```
$ find adir_.~1~/ -ls
10757186    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 saml     saml         4096 Oct 14 23:54 adir_.~1~/
10370964    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml            0 Oct 14 23:50 adir_.~1~/afile_.~1~
```

Now move the dir + file:

```
$ mv adir_.~1~/ adir
$ mv adir/afile_.~1~ adir/afile
```

And confirm:

```
$ find adir/ -ls
10757186    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 saml     saml         4096 Oct 15 00:01 adir/
10370964    0 -rw-rw-r--   1 saml     saml            0 Oct 14 23:50 adir/afile
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename all files and the directory in one go, you can use the [`rename`](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/pl_src/rename/rename.html) command, which at least on Debian-based Linux distributions is included with the `perl` package:

```
rename 's/\.~1~$//' */*.~1~ underscore.~1~
```

The first argument to `rename` is a Perl Regular Expression, which describes the substitution to be done. Subsequent arguments are file names to operate on. Note that in order to manage with only a single invocation, the directory is specified last to avoid the path to the files within from changing after the argument path expansion takes place.